# PostgreSQL-9.1 watching the schema changes

Tags: c++, postgresql, schema

ALL,

I am writing a software using C++ which will connect to the database and perform some operations and then disconnect. The program will be using different DBMSs and it will be cross-platform. The software should check for the schema changes and if there is a table creation / modification / deletion, act accordingly.

One of the challenges I'm currently facing is this:

I'm trying to test the software on one of the old Mac computers with the PostgreSQL-9.1 installed. The newer versions of PostgreSQL supports writing the function which will look for the schema changes and notify the client. But this feature is available from the version 9.3.

Is there an easy and simple way to get such notification for PG-9.1 and 9.2? Or the only way is to work with the log file and do the polling of it?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

There's also `infromation_schema` which presents a standardized representation of the shape of the database, you could query that and compare before and after results.

Comment: I can but I was hoping to avoid that